# classicthesis with XeLaTeX, font issue

Tags: xetex, fontspec, classicthesis, arsclassica

I'm using macOS 10.15 and TeXlive 2020 with MacTeX. When trying to compile (with `xelatex`) a document that uses `classicthesis` with the following option:

```tex
\RequirePackage[eulerchapternumbers,eulermath,style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}
```

I get multiple errors of `fontspec` telling me "Font <somefont> not find". After a bit searching, I have no other choice but to manually install these fonts:

```
texgyrepagella-regular.otf
texgyrepagella-math.otf
Iwona-Regular.otf
```

Now the file gets compiled, but the result is not good as using `pdflatex`:

1. The `eulermath` option has no effects (since `eulervm`, even adding `OT1` option, doesn't work here, thought I don't know why), so I have to write explicitly:

```
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}
```

which partially solves the problem, but need me to manually install `euler.otf`.

2. The letter spacing doesn't work. I find this in `classicthesis.sty`:

```tex
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=18.0}\ct@caps\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}% WordSpace=1.8
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{{\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=14.0}\ct@caps\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}% WordSpace=1.8
```

but this `\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=18.0}` doesn't work, and the title looks like this:
[image: result with xelatex]
which should be like: [image: result with pdflatex]

If I write explicitly:

```tex
\chapter{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=18.0} Introduction}
```

then I get this error:

```
LaTeX3: The key 'fontspec-opentype/LETTERSPACE' is unknown and is
(LaTeX3)    being ignored.
```

I would like to know:

1. Is it only me or everyone using Mac with `xelatex` need to manually find the font files and install them? I've done a lot of search on this site, and it seems if I want to use `fontspec` with font name (not file name), then I would have to find the file, click and install it before using it.
2. More importantly, is there a way to make this line-spacing working?

---

Here is a MWE:

```tex
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{iftex}
\RequirePackage{mathpazo} % math font
\ifTUTeX\else%
\PassOptionsToPackage{defaultsups}{newpxtext}
\RequirePackage{newpxtext} % to simulate the [sc,osf] effect of mathpazo, while keeping the bf+sc font
\useosf % old-style figures in text, not in math
\fi
\PassOptionsToPackage{euler-digits,small}{eulervm}

\RequirePackage[eulerchapternumbers,eulermath,style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}
\ifTUTeX%
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}
\fi


\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Some title}

SOME TEXT

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please try with `\protect`, i.e., `\chapter{\protect\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=18.0} Introduction}`, note that I'm not in system, hence I gave approximate suggestion only....

Comment: @MadyYuvi, I just tried and this error remains. I think it is a pure font issue, that this feature can be applied to `.otf` fonts.

Comment: @XuJinwen Using `\addfontfeatture` inside a chapter title is surely not the solution. Can you please add a minimal example, from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`, to play with?

Comment: @MadyYuvi using `\protect` on a command would not stop its argument being uppercased.

Comment: @egreg I just added a MWE at the bottom of the question. It reproduces the effect mentioned above (at least on my mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions of `\spacedallcaps` and `\spacedlowsmallcaps` seem wrong, because they first apply letter spacing, but then change to a different font and the setting is forgotten.

You can fix it as follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{iftex}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
  \setsansfont{Iwona}
\else
  \usepackage[defaultsups]{newpxtext}
  \useosf
\fi
\PassOptionsToPackage{euler-digits,small}{eulervm}
\RequirePackage[eulerchapternumbers,eulermath,style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}

\ifTUTeX
  \setmathfont[math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}
\fi

\makeatletter
\protected\def\spacedlowsmallcaps#1{%
 {\ct@caps\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=18.0}\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}%
}
\protected\def\spacedallcaps#1{%
 {\ct@caps\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=18.0}\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Some title}

Some text

\textsf{INTRODUCTION} \spacedallcaps{INTRODUCTION}

$a+b=12$

\end{document}
```

How to load fonts? It depends on whether you installed them as system fonts or not. The above code works for me, because I did. Otherwise you need to use the TeX Live ones. Replace the relevant part as follows.

```
\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{texgyrepagella}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
  ]
  \setsansfont{Iwona}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  ]
\else
  \usepackage[defaultsups]{newpxtext}
  \useosf
\fi
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to ask two more question: 1. Is it proper to keep using `mathpazo` with xelatex? For I prefer the `\mathbb` font of it. 2. Is there a better way than "find-file-and-click" to install fonts distributed in TeXlive as system font?

Comment: @XuJinwen That's a different question. If you do `\setmathfont`, loading `mathpazo` is completely useless. You can redefine `\mathbb` later, though.

Comment: I think it is not completely useless. Take the above example, without `mathpazo`, `\mathbb{R}` looks just like letter "R" in Euler font, but with `mathpazo`, it's a px-style font. @egreg

Comment: @XuJinwen *Loading* `mathpazo` is useless, because its setting might be overridden by `unicode-math`. You need a slightly different strategy, for instance  `\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbb{U}{fplmbb}{m}{n}}` after having loaded all packages.